# Unable to create AWS Lambda layer: "SSL validation failed ... EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2423)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am trying to create a layer based on the ready-made zip file here: https://github.com/diegoparrilla/headless-chrome-aws-lambda-layer

The zip file is 80mb, which is larger than the maximum allowable console direct upload size of 50mb, but I verified the unzipped size is 211mb, which is smaller than the maximum allowable total unzipped size of 250mb.

I have verified I am able to access my AWS account using keys stored in the configurations, and I am using us-east-1 location.

I run the following: `aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name layer-headless_chrome-v0.2-beta.0 --zip-file fileb://layer-headless_chrome-v0.2-beta.0.zip --compatible-runtimes "python3.8"`

And it produces the following error: `botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2018-10-31/layers/layer-headless_chrome-v0.2-beta.0/versions EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2423)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to separate the S3 upload task from publish-layer-version task, the CLI is still subject to the 50 MB size limit for a packaged upload of a zipped lambda layer. Uploading to S3 first as a discrete step and then invoking publish-layer-version with the --content parameter should allow your subsequent task to succeed.

```
aws s3 cp layer-headless_chrome-v0.2-beta.0.zip s3://<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>/layer-headless_chrome.zip
aws lambda publish-layer-version \
    --layer-name HeadlessChromium \
    --region <YOUR_AWS_REGION> \
    --content S3Bucket=<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>,S3Key=layer-headless_chrome.zip \
    --compatible-runtimes python3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your `~/.aws/config` file

```
[profile whatever]
s3 =
  max_concurrent_requests = 20
  max_queue_size = 10000
  multipart_threshold = 64MB
  multipart_chunksize = 16MB
  max_bandwidth = 50MB/s
  addressing_style = path
```

Worked like charm after trying to fix it for hours!!

Comment: i still got a size limit with this suggestion unfortumately "An error occurred (RequestEntityTooLargeException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: Request must be smaller than 70167211 bytes for the UpdateFunctionCode operation"